# IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, machine-learning, py4j

I was doing the assignment of "advanced machine learning and signal processing" in Coursera. I get the encountered with this error "Py4JavaEror". 
This is the first assignment of this course. It was said to be done in IBM Watson studio but doing it in Ibm Watson studio to too complex and I did in google Colab. 
Here is my code:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
def printmd(string):
   display(Markdown('# <span style="color:red">'+string+'</span>'))

if ('sc' in locals() or 'sc' in globals()):
   printmd('<<<<<!!!!! It seems that you are running in a IBM Watson Studio!>>>>>')

!pip install pyspark==2.4.5
try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
except ImportError as e:
    printmd('<<<<<!!!!! Please restart your kernel after installing Apache Spark !!!!!>>>>>')


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
spark = SparkSession \
           .builder \
           .getOrCreate()

df=spark.read.load('a2.parquet')

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("SELECT * from df").show()
```

Error is like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

4 frames
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o530.load.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'
```

Here,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the run time version of your java is 11

> Spark runs on Java 8, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.4 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x)

Try installing a different java with of version 8 and point your `JAVA_HOME` to the newly installed java.