# Unit Tests in GHA failing with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, github-actions, cicd

I've inherited a codebase that hasn't been touched for around 3 years. I've noticed that a large number of unit tests in our GitHub action for the repo are failing with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
```

A quick google suggested that I needed to update to Java 11, so I added the following step to our `main.yml`:

```
- name: Set up Java
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    distribution: 'zulu'
    java-version: '11'
```

But the tests are still failing with the same error.

Can anyone lend a hand with this?

Comment: Thanks @DmytroMitin did you want to make that an answer and I will mark it as the accepted one?

Comment: done :) good that this helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or vice versa this can mean that you need to downgrade to Java less than 11 because one of dependencies doesn't work with Java 11

---

[Spark Error - Unsupported class file major version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/spark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version)

[IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021734/illegalargumentexception-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55)

[Spark: IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019548/spark-illegalargumentexception-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55)

[How can I fix "unsupported class file major version 60" in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea)

[How to fix 'Unsupported class file major version 55' while executing 'org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet.collectAsList()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923943/how-to-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55-while-executing-org-apache)